# Run Scripts from PHP

Tags: php, linux, scripting, steam

I have a question about interaction PHP and Linux system.

I want to launch Steam from WebPage, and address of this page is

```
http://site.eu/cp/user/services/21/steaminstall
```

And internal path to WebPage from where im running command is

```
/var/www/wwwuser/data/www/site.eu/panel.php?(here goes $_POST[''] data)
```

and the Steam Client is

```
/var/www/wwwuser/data/Steam/SteamInstall
```

The thing is, i know how to access this script, also i can execute simple

```
echo "Script is Runing"
```

But when my actions comes to this code

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -P /var/www/aftersoft/data/Servers/Steam/ http://media.steampowered.com/client/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz &&
tar xvfz /var/www/aftersoft/data/Servers/Steam/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz -C /var/www/aftersoft/data/Servers/Steam/ &&
sh /var/www/aftersoft/data/Servers/Steam/steamcmd.sh +login anonymous +quit &&
rm /var/www/aftersoft/data/Servers/Steam/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz &&
echo "Steam Installation and Update Completed"
```

It's not doing anything if im running it from WebPage, but it works when im trying to run it under the SSH user (same as apache user with permissions to write to this folder)

So my question, what am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
My php code to run script is

```
if($path[2] === 'steaminstall')
{
    $InstallSteam = exec('/var/www/aftersoft/data/Servers/Steam/SteamInstall', $Output, $Error);
    if($Error === 0)
    {
      $Status = $DB->SteamStatus($_SESSION['username']);
      if($Status)
      {
         header('Location: /cp/'.$_SESSION['username'].'/services/');
      }
      else
      {
         $Smarty->assign('InstallStatus', 'Database Error Occured');
         $Smarty->display('steaminstall.tpl');
      }
    }
    if($Error === 2)
    {
       $Smarty->assign('InstallStatus', $Output);
       $Smarty->display('steaminstall.tpl');
    }
}
```

And this is my database query function

```
public function SteamStatus($Username)
{
    $Status = '1';
    $Statement = $this->DBConnection->prepare("UPDATE account set steaminstalled = ? where username = ?");
    $Statement->bindParam(1, $Status);
    $Statement->bindParam(2, $Username);
    $IStatus = $Statement->execute();
    if($IStatus)
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about your php code?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, you just need to specify direct path to your script (as if you dont, the script itself dont know where to download and where to extract)

So the final bash script (PHP part is perfectly fine):

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -P /var/www/aftersoft/data/Servers/Steam/ http://media.steampowered.com/client/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz &&
tar xvfz /var/www/aftersoft/data/Servers/Steam/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz -C /var/www/aftersoft/data/Servers/Steam/ &&
sh /var/www/aftersoft/data/Servers/Steam/steamcmd.sh +login anonymous +quit &&
rm /var/www/aftersoft/data/Servers/Steam/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz &&
echo "Steam Installation and Update Completed"
```